# Launching macros from second keyboard

Tags: windows-7, productivity, keyboard-shortcuts

I have two keyboards connected to my computer. I am looking for a program that allows to launch macros by pressing keys on my second keyboard (but pressing the same keys on my first keyboard shouldn't trigger them).

I am looking for a solution for Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate. So far I have found [AHKHID](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/38015-ahkhid-an-ahk-implementation-of-the-hid-functions/) but it seems tedious to use and I have seen people reporting issues with Windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [HID macros](http://www.hidmacros.eu/news.php):

- free
- works with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate
- allows to launch macros by pressing keys on my second keyboard (but pressing the same keys on my first keyboard shouldn't trigger them). More generally, the program allows you to assign a macro to a given key on a specific keyboard (provided that it is recognized as a HID).
- This utility is written mainly for Flight Simluator (with extra feature for FSX Deluxe version), but can be also usefull if you want to activate keyboard macros from special keyboard(s)
- still maintained: the last version is dated 3.10.2013.

Script commands contain:

- extended keystrokes with windows management
- mouse events - single clicks, double clicks, all buttons
- windows script host - Shell or Network objects are accessible
- FSX events - any FSX event can be sent by HIDmacros command from script
- FSX variables - HIDmacros can monitor selected FSX variables and their values can be read by special command
- FSUIPC interface - access to FS variables
- buffer - simple input interface for scripts
- game devices - support for toggle switches
- game axis - read joystick position in script
- X-plane - read & set X-plane variables, execute commands

[image]

[image]

Note that you could also get a [gamepad with mappable keys](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/179838-28-keyboards-possible) such as [Cyber Snipa's gamepad](http://www.cybersnipa.com/us/gaming-keyboards/gamepad.php).

[image]

Comment: HID macros has been superseeded by [LuaMacros (Github)](https://github.com/me2d13/luamacros) ([Release download](http://www.hidmacros.eu/luamacros.zip))